# Trying to use async.forEach Serially but Fails - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, foreach, node-async

forEach , i am using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library . in the foreach loop i will call a different service and get data . those data should be in order to process it in my view , because these are some dress details and need to be in order . so i tried to make the foreach loop synchronous by adding the `done()` inside the external service callback.

```
var address_deails = [];
var x = 0;

async.forEach(lat_long, function (item, done) {
    external_servie(item,config,function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            //code here .......
            address_deails[x]  = //some_data;
        }
        x++;
        done();  <------------- Here 
    });
}, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        callback(err,null)
    } else {
        callback(err,address_deails)
    }
});
```

but i am getting values in a different order each time .

I want to get array keys in order like  `0,1,2` .

As per my knowledge i thought if you use `done()` inside the callback , until the callback returns , the forEach loop will wait .

Does the `async.forEach` work differently  ?

Can you give me any suggestion so that i can solve my issue , may using an other library than async .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Does the `async` has `forEach`?

Comment: What version of async are you using? I don't think the current has forEach? async.each does not guarantee the series will be run in order.

Comment: @Seonixx my version is 1.4.2

Comment: @Jai yes , i am using 1.4.2  . is there any other libraries i can use to achieve this ?

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya https://github.com/caolan/async#collections i doubt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`async.forEach()`](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L207) is an alias for `async.each` and the doc says:

> Note, that since this function applies  iteratee  to each item in parallel, there is no guarantee that the iteratee functions will complete in order.

What you're looking for is `async.eachSeries()`/`async.forEachSeries()`:

```
async.eachSeries(lat_long, function (item, done) {
    external_servie(item,config,function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            //code here .......
            address_deails[x]  = //some_data;
        }
        x++;
        done();  <------------- Here 
    });
}, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        callback(err,null)
    } else {
        callback(err,address_deails)
    }
});
```

And now you can push into `address_deails` instead of maintaining an index: `address_deails.push(/* some data */);`.

There is also an issue on your external_service's error management:

```
external_servie(item,config,function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        done(err); // <<< call done with the error to stop the loop or it will continue
    } else {
        //code here .......
        address_deails.push(/* some data */);        
    }
    done();  <------------- Here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous function to correct index:

```
async.forEach(lat_long, function (item, done) {
  (function(index) {
    external_servie(item,config,function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            //code here .......
            address_deails[index]  = //some_data;
        }
        done();  <------------- Here 
    });
  })(x);
  x++
}, function(err) {
        console.log(err,address_deails)
});
```